# Ocaml is the element in the list of lists

Tags: ocaml

I have created a list of lists, for example:

```
list1 = [[1; 2]; [3; 4]]
```

I'm trying to create a function "is_element", which would return true if intiger is in the list, and false otherwise.

How should it work:

```
is_element list1 4;;
- : bool = true
```

What I tried:

```
let rec is_element x = function
[[]] -> false
| [(a:int)::l] -> (a:int) == x || is_element x [l];;
```

I do get a warning and this function doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Your function does not cover all cases to start with. For example, the case of [] being passed to the function is not covered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
let rec is_element x lst = 
let rec aux y = function
  [] -> false
  | a::l -> a==y || aux y l
in
match lst with
  [] -> false
  | a::l -> aux x a || is_element x l;;
```

You can use an auxiliary function to check if an element is contained in a list, and then apply this function to the elements of your list of lists.
Then you should invoke this function with

```
is_element 4 list1;;
```

or invert the order of the parameters (x and lst).

Answer (score 5):

You can use [List.mem](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/List.html#VALmem) to check if an element is part of a list, and you can use
[List.exists](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/List.html#VALexists) to check whether any element of a list satisfies a predicate.
Combining these two you can check if a list of lists contains your elements.